# cyclejs extract target from input text during map operation

Tags: typescript, cyclejs

```
 Main.ts

    const clickMessages$ = sources.DOM
            .select('.add')
            .events('click');

        const latitudeMinimum$ = sources.DOM
            .select('.latitudeMinimum')
            .events('input');

        const latitudeMaximum$ = sources.DOM
            .select('.latitudeMaximum')
            .events('input');


        const latituteRange$ = xs.combine(latitudeMinimum$, latitudeMaximum$); 

        const newStream$ = xs.combine(clickMessages$, latituteRange$);
        const filter$ = newStream$.filter(c => { return true });
        const map$ = filter$.map(([a, [b, c]]) => { return [b.target.value, c.target.value] } 
// <<--- b.target.value won't compile... was expecting to get my value from input field
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, the `target` of a DOM event is of type `EventTarget` as you can see here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L3661 The generic `EventTarget` type only has a few methods.

In your case, you know exactly what kind of element will be in the target. 
So in order to tell the compiler that your `target` has the `value` property, you need to cast it into a more concrete type (`HTMLInputElement for example https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L5248)

I don't think you can do that in a single shot (or at least I am not aware of a technique to do that), so you would need another `map`.

```
const latitudeMinValue$ = latitudeMinimum$
  .map(event => event.target)
  .map((element: HTMLInputElemnet) => element.name)

const latitudeMaxValue$ = latitudeMaximum$
  .map(event => event.target)
  .map((element: HTMLInputElemnet) => element.name)

const latituteRange$ = xs.combine(latitudeMinValue$, latitudeMaxValue$)
  .map(/*([minValue, maxValue])*/);
```

An even cleaner way to do this (as we are repeating the `map().map()` twice, so we are not very DRY) we can use the `compose` operator given by `xstream`.

```
function eventToTargetValue(event$ Stream<Event>) {
  return event$.map(event => event.target)
    .map((element: HTMLInputElement) => element.value)
}

const latitudeMinValue$ = latitudeMinimum$
  .compose(eventToTargetValue)

const latitudeMaxValue$ = latitudeMaximum$
  .compose(eventToTargetValue)

const latituteRange$ = xs.combine(latitudeMinValue$, latitudeMaxValue$)
  .map(/*([minValue, maxValue])*/);
```

Hope it helps :)